# Is there a way to find a bidirectional relationship between nodes in NetworkX?

Tags: python, twitter, networkx, graph-theory

I have a network of Twitter users and their followers which I am modelling using NetworkX. I am trying to find a bidirectional link between users, i.e. if one node follows one of its neighbors, does that neighbor also follow that node.

Is there a built in function within NetworkX that would accomplish this? I tried using `nx.reciprocity()` but it just returns a single value rather than a dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can determine if there is an edge connection between two nodes with [`networkx.Graph.has_edge`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable//reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.has_edge.html). This could then be used to test if there are opposite directed edges between nodes.

```python
import networkx as nx

def have_bidirectional_relationship(G, node1, node2):
    return G.has_edge(node1, node2) and G.has_edge(node2, node1)


G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edge(1, 2)
G.add_edge(2, 1)
G.add_edge(3, 4)

print(f"Nodes 1, 2 have opposite edges: {have_bidirectional_relationship(G, 1, 2)}")
print(f"Nodes 3, 4 have opposite edges: {have_bidirectional_relationship(G, 3, 4)}")
```

#### Output

```
Nodes 1, 2 have opposite edges: True
Nodes 3, 4 have opposite edges: False
```

## Find all nodes with bidirectional relationships

```
biconnections = set()
for u, v in G.edges():
    if u > v:  # Avoid duplicates, such as (1, 2) and (2, 1)
        v, u = u, v
    if have_bidirectional_relationship(G, u, v):
        biconnections.add((u, v))

print(biconnections)
```

#### Output

```
{(1, 2)}
```

Comment: Hi Christopher, This looks like something similar to what I need. I am trying to find a way to find all bidirectional links a node may have. Would your solution work by looping over all nodes and edges and call the function and compile at the end? Or is there a more elegant way to accomplish this?

Comment: Once you have the set of all pairs of nodes with bidirectional relationships (as shown in the answer), then for each node in the set, you could create a dictionary mapping each node to a list of its bidirectional connections.

Comment: Thanks Christopher, I'm new to networkx and graph theory this is exactly what I need